# Como usar TrackBy no ngFor em Angular?

Tags: angular

Olá, tenho uma estrutura de repetição onde pode ser aplicado um pipe filter.Tenho lido que o trackBy pode auxiliar no desempenho pois não renderiza desnecessariamente o DOM.

Coloquei no meu componente:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {    
    return item.id; //Aplicado trackbyfn para melhorar performance do *ngFor
}
```

No meu template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let calculo of calculos;let m = index; trackBy: trackByFn" class="table-line">
```

Estou fazendo corretamente? Tem que passar algum valor específico para o trackby ou só passar a função já é suficiente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passar uma função para o trackBy é o suficiente.

O que você está fazendo é informar ao Angular um Id único para cada elemento renderizando de seu array, dessa forma ao adicionar ou remover algum elemento não será renderizados a árvore completa novamente.

Espero ter ajudado.